# Responsive Chart.js based on a size of a browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js, sveltekit

I'd like to have a responsive graph using Chart.js on my Svelte app. The size of the chart should follow the browser window size. I currently have a chart on a div container. However, it doesn't work expectedly, as I expected the chart is getting bigger when the browser window size is bigger. It gets smaller when I downsize the browser window.

It seems that the container size is following the browser size but the chart canvas. I tried to control the canvas size programmatically by adding the code below.

```
const clientHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('chart-container')[0].clientHeight;
const clientWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('chart-container')[0].clientWidth;
chart.canvas.height = clientHeight;
chart.canvas.width = clientWidth;
```

I got the height and width of the container, but it didn't work too. What can I do more?

Here is the code.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

    let data = [20, 100, 50, 12, 20, 130, 45];
    let labels = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    let ctx;
    let canvas;

    onMount(() => {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            options: {
                layout: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false
                }
            },
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Unit Sales',
                        data: data
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas bind:this={canvas} />
</div>

<style>
    div {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to remove the inline styling from the `<canvas>` holding the graph and define your own CSS properties with size values for class `.s-HkQ....`.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thank you for your comment. It seems that the Chart generates the style automatically. I'd like to know how to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not

```
options: {
    layout: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
},
```

but

```
options: {                                              
    maintainAspectRatio: false              
},
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d901f69c790d4a71bb600158c2a734d7?version=3.55.0)